# android - normal activity with in a tab activity

Tags: android, tabbar

in my app i have two activities one is of tab activity with 5 tabs and other is of a normal activity.

At first when the app is launched i am showing the normal activity A, which is not related to tab activity, but here is need to show the 5 tab buttons in the bottom with all in un-selected  mode.

how to show a normal activity with a list of tab button used in the app

is this a possible one ?

Comment: So let me get this straight: You want to know how to show tabs in the activity which doesn't have tabs? Can I ask why?

Comment: @Warpzit - according to my app design i need to show like that....

Comment: Yes but what I don't get is: Should they look like the tabs or should you just have buttons that direct to the tabs in the other activity?

Comment: yes it must look like the tabs....

Comment: But then I gotta ask why have you as the app designed decided to split it up into 2 activities? Are you using MapActivity?

Comment: yes exactly i am having the map to be the first view, with five points marked on it. if the user clicks any of the points it must get moved to tabs activity....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do with out of the box components. So let me suggest some alternatives.

1. You could do like Google. What Google does in Maps and Navigation is that they use the actionbar with overflow buttons. If you look at the two apps you'll see that these buttons works a little like tabs. When the user then clicks these they could be navigated to the other activity with the real tabs in them or you could use the overflow buttons as the actual tab bar.
2. Use Osmdroid as it have maps and it can be used without having to implement it as a `MapActivity`.
3. As a last solution you could make your own tabs...

Comment: Warpzit - can you answer the following question stackoverflow.com/questions/13621432/… - i need a solution for this....

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to put list view in tabHost. Instead of that do this.

Main Activity - Where you implement the tabHost. Here you can create tabs and link it to specific activity.

**FirstTabActivity -** Implement your code here with your ListView as like normal activity.

**SecondTabActivity -** Implement your code here with your ListView as like normal activity.

**ThirdTabActivity -** Implement your code here with your ListView as like normal activity.

And So On.

EDIT

Tutorial - See Here.

Comment: You forgot to add the tutorial link